# how to avoid 'System.OutOfMemoryException' Merging large number of PDF files using iTextSharp in asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext, out-of-memory

I am merging large number of pdf files using iTextSharp in asp.net mvc c#, it works fine for small number of files but when it reaches about (1000) files it breaks on line pdf.AddDocument(reader); and throws  'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
I am already using PdfCopy and FileStream to better utilize memory which is suggested every where I searched. My code is given below. Please suggest me how to handle this.

```
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(outMergeFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
            PdfReader reader = null;
            PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
            try
            {
                document.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)
                {
                    var fileStr = Request.MapPath(fileList[i].Path)                            
                    reader = new PdfReader(fileStr);
                        
                    pdf.AddDocument(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                document.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you running IIS in 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, I am using IIS in 64-bit.

Comment: Either improve your implementation or add more ram, there is no way around it.

Comment: Your code is not quite correct. `Document, PdfCopy, PdfReader` are disposable objects. They must have `using` statements. They should all be inside the `for` loop; not outside.

Comment: @KosalaW in case of itext `Dispose` and `Close` essentially do the same and the op attempts to close. Thus, they do not have to use `using`. But it definitively would be good style.

Comment: Except in the case of `PdfCopy` - here it is actually an error that the class implemented disposable.

Comment: Consider doing `pdf.FreeReader(reader)` right before `reader.Close()`. That method is documented as *Use this method to writes the reader to the document and **free the memory used by it**.  The main use is when concatenating multiple documents to keep the memory usage restricted to the current appending document.*

Comment: Thanks @mkl, pdf.FreeReader(reader) worked for me.

Comment: Ok, great! Shall I write a proper answer to accept or do you want to do so yourself?

Comment: you can write the answer I will accept that, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```csharp
pdf.FreeReader(reader);
```

right before

```csharp
reader.Close();
```

to make sure that as little memory as possible is required for managing copied content from that `reader`.

That method (of the parent class of `PdfCopy`) is documented as *Writes the reader to the document and **frees the memory used by it**. The main use is when concatenating multiple documents to keep the memory usage restricted to the current appending document.*